# The Metaslitherlink

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, slitherlink

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #13: Variety Slitherlinks](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/monthly-topic-challenge-13-variety-slitherlinks).</sub>

---

Below is a grid containing multiple small slitherlinks. These can be independently solved to form clues for the large metaslitherlink.

The following standard rules apply to all slitherlinks:

- Connect adjacent dots with vertical or horizontal lines to make a single loop.
- The numbers indicate how many lines surround it, while empty cells may be surrounded by any number of lines.
- The loop never crosses itself and never branches off.

The solved metaslitherlink should reveal a number, which is the final answer to this puzzle.

[image: metaslitherlink]

Comment: Nice twist on the small slitherlinks connection to the big one!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Answer:

> **256**

Let's first solve the small slitherlinks:

> [image: small slitherlinks]

For most of the small slitherlinks I think I know what they mean:

> [image: small slitherlinks solution]

> I just don't know what the Pi symbol means. It's not `3.14` rounded to 3, because then there is no solution possible. Maybe a zero, (because you can't do full circles in slitherlink, the Pi symbol is almost a closed circle), but that generates some negative values (for example, R2C3 will be `-3`. I tried to interpret those as a 5, because then all the calculations made sense, but that gives not a unique final solution. And what is the symbol in R3C4 supposed to mean?
>  **Edit:** as pointed out in the comments: it's not a Pi symbol, it is a `N` for a number not yet known. And `N` equals to `4`. The symbol in R4C6 reads `nil`. Thanks @Arturo and @Samm82.

> If I interpret it as 4, I get the following:
>  [image: finalsolution]

And I think this could be the final answer:

> **`4^4 = 256`**

Comment: I got stuck with the N too, but didn't like case-bashing so I left the meta grid unsolved. I think R3C4 is supposed to say "nil" rather that "n-n".

Comment: The "case-bashing" here doesn't seem that bad to me- n has to be at least 3 (or else R2C3 is negative) and is at most 5 (or else R5C5 is negative), so there is only 3 cases to consider (n = {3, 4, 5}); I would try solving the metagrid _without_ the n-based clues and see if any more constraints on them come up.

Comment: Nice solve, well done! I settled on using the variable 'n' (running the risk that it could be interpreted as 'pi') because other letters, like 'x' are too awkward to draw in a rectangular grid :)